# Pig: summing column b of rows with the same column a

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to count the number of tweets with a certain hashtag over a period of time but I'm getting an error when trying to use the built-in SUM function.

Example:

```
  data = LOAD 'tweets_2.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (date:float,hashtag:chararray,count:int,   year:int, month:int, day:int, hour:int, minute:int, second:int);
  NBLNabilVoto_count = FILTER data BY hashtag == 'NBLNabilaVoto';   
   NBLNabilVoto_group = GROUP NBLNabilVoto by count;
   X = FOREACH NBLNabilVoto GENERATE group, SUM(data.count);
```

Error:

```
<line 22, column 47> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I sum the count column attribute of a bag of rows?

Comment: Your script has a lot of problems in it. Go through each line and make sure you understand what it's doing. Use `DESCRIBE` for each relation you create to understand what fields it includes.

Answer (score 0):

First Load the data then filter for the time interval you want to process. Group the record based on the hashtag. Use count() function to count the number of twitter for the corresponding hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the code is doing what you think or want it to do but the error you are getting is because you are doing a `SUM` on the wrong thing.  You need to do this

`X = FOREACH NBLNabilVoto GENERATE group, SUM(NBLNabilVoto_count.count);`

`NBLNabilVoto_count`  is the name of the tuples in the databag

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using the wrong realtion in your SUM, you could SUM NBLNabilVoto_count not data realtion. i have question why you are groupping by COUNT ?

if you want count all your tweet with hashtag NBLNabilVoto.

i think the code must be like :

```
data = LOAD 'tweets_2.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (date:float,hashtag:chararray,count:int,   year:int, month:int, day:int, hour:int, minute:int, second:int);
  NBLNabilVoto_count = FILTER data BY hashtag == 'NBLNabilaVoto';   
   NBLNabilVoto_group = GROUP NBLNabilVoto by all;
   X = FOREACH NBLNabilVoto GENERATE group, SUM(NBLNabilVoto_count.count.count);
```